# All nginx access logs from 127.0.0.1 (so can't use fail2ban)

Tags: nginx, drupal, fail2ban

**Problem**

I'm trying to configure fail2ban to block ddos attacks using the chunk shown [here](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/anti-nginx-dos-filter-for-fail2ban-4/).

Basically it looks at all requests and if any single IP makes more than 240 requests over 60 seconds it blocks them for two days.

However all the logs in my nginx access are from 127.0.0.1 which makes the whole thing pointless.

What could cause nginx to log all traffic as coming from the server?

(I'm running Drupal on a LEMP stack with [perusio's nginx config](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx).)

Comment: What are you running in front of nginx?

Comment: Hmm. Varnish. I'd not thought of that. Shoot that would explain it. I'm going to need to somehow get the logs from varnish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have varnish in front of nginx, it thinks all the requests are coming from 127.0.0.1, since technically they are.

To resolve this, use the [nginx real ip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to pick the client's IP address out of the `X-Forwarded-For` header, which Varnish automatically adds to requests (unless you told it not to).

An example nginx configuration would be:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael you've just rescued my Sunday afternoon. As it turns out the chunk is actually in Perusio's config but I just hadn't understood the purpose and so I hadn't set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The example piece of configuration Micheal is talking about is in the top level nginx config at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf if you're using Perusio's config.

```
http {
    ## MIME types.
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ## FastCGI.
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    ## Default log and error files.
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ## Use sendfile() syscall to speed up I/O operations and speed up
    ## static file serving.
    sendfile on;
    ## Handling of IPs in proxied and load balancing situations.
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/32; # all addresses get a real IP.
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For; # the ip is forwarded from the load balancer/proxy
```

You need to change 0.0.0.0/32 to 127.0.0.1.